# Cron jobs run 1 hour off, in total disagreement with system times

Tags: cron

**Example of issue:**

```
* 9 * * * echo 9
* 10 * * * echo 10
```

The above will fire off an email to the user every minute, but all the "9" responses will happen at 10:00AM -> 10:59AM, while the "10"s will come in at 11:00AM->11:59AM.

Running a job of

```
* * * * * /bin/date ; /bin/date -u
```

Returned the expected (correct) date and time. this was true for both UTC and local time (America/Denver). Change this job to run every minute at a specific hour results in the offset (jobs told to run at 9 run at 10, etc etc).

**Current debug I have completed:**

Okay, thats odd. Maybe my timezone file is somehow messed up? Lets check that

```
diff -s /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/`cat /etc/timezone`
Files /etc/localtime and /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Denver are identical
```

I have checked the hardware clock to see if this is off or somehow disagrees with my local settings (run as root).

```
date ; hwclock
Wed Oct 26 10:50:13 MDT 2016
Wed 26 Oct 2016 10:50:14 AM MDT  -0.204171 seconds
```

Looks to be off by a second, but that shouldn't make my cron jobs run a full hour off schedule, right?

I am also sure of the following:

- Has my timezone changed recently? **No**
- Did you try manually fixing the timezone anyway? **Yes**
- Did you reset cron after fixing the timezone? **Yes**
- Have I made sure that the cron service was restarted? **Yes**
- Have I restarted the cron service? **Yes**
- Are you really sure that cron was restarted? **100% sure Cron has been restarted**

Other potentially relevant information:

Running Debian.

```
cat /etc/debian_version
8.6
```

Current Kernel

```
uname -a
Linux BigBox 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Updated Debug:**

Ran 'hwclock --systohc', not noticeable changes to behavior. Ran this command to check

```
date;hwclock
Wed Oct 26 12:39:09 MDT 2016
Wed 26 Oct 2016 12:39:11 PM MDT  -0.875328 seconds
```

I cannot run 'cat /etc/sysconfig/clock' as this file does not exist. Running a find command under the /etc/ tree to find 'clock' confirms that I have no file by that name there.

Checked to see if anything I am aware of has set the CRON_TZ variable. It is not set at the user level, nor at roots level. Have cron echo them out gives no output.

Comment: Is the `CRON_TZ` env var set anywhere?

Comment: try `hwclock --systohc` just for completeness, and add `cat /etc/sysconfig/clock` to question ?

Comment: Added both suggestions to my information, sadly neither provided much of value. CRON_TZ isn't set under any environment I can see, re-syncing the hwclock gave the same results as before (checked anyway to see if it changed, it did not) and I don't have an '/etc/sysconfig/clock' file.

Answer (score 1):

One more place to look: the start-at-boot script(s) for `cron`, or the old school system crontab file `/etc/crontab` .  It's possible that the TZ environment variable gets set in, say, `/etc/init.d/cronie` or `/lib/systemd/system/crond.service`, I'm not sure what Debian uses for init system.

I've seen something like this when I tried to have `crond` run things every other hour:

```
0 */2 * * * /opt/dbms/rainstor/archiving/ama_term
```

`crond` ran the script on odd-numbered hours. I suspected, but never proved to myself, that it had to do with a daylight savings time confusion.

Comment: /etc/init.d/cron is grabbing the `/etc/timezone` file.  TZ=`cat /etc/timezone`. That file appears to be correct (Ran a checksum just to be double sure its identical to what it should be.). /lib/systemd/system/crond.service doesn't seem to want to modify any TZ variables.

I'm going to check the */2 suggestion to see if I am seeing the same thing.